# Draw Multiple Rectangles in One View using drawRect and onTouch on Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I can draw a single rectangle but cannot draw a new one once a button is clicked. Please help!  I want to draw a new rectangle for every touch and drag. Thanks in advance!

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(points[3]==null) //point4 null when user did not touch and move on screen.
        return;
    int left, top, right, bottom;
    left = points[0].x;
    top = points[0].y;
    right = points[0].x;
    bottom = points[0].y;
    for (int i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
        left = left > points[i].x ? points[i].x:left;
        top = top > points[i].y ? points[i].y:top;
        right = right < points[i].x ? points[i].x:right;
        bottom = bottom < points[i].y ? points[i].y:bottom;
    }
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    //draw stroke
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#AADB1255"));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    canvas.drawRect(
                left + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
                top + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
                right + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
                bottom + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, paint);

    //fill the rectangle
    paint.setStyle(paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#55DB1255"));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    canvas.drawRect(
            left + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
            top + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
            right + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, 
            bottom + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, paint);

    //draw the corners
    BitmapDrawable bitmap = new BitmapDrawable();
     //draw the balls on the canvcasPaint
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setTextSize(22);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    for (int i =0; i < colorballs.size(); i ++) {
        ColorBall ball = colorballs.get(i);

        switch(i) {
        case 0:
            ax = ball.getX();
            ay = ball.getY();
            break;
        case 1:
            bx = ball.getX();
            by = ball.getY();

            width = Math.round(Math.sqrt((double) ((bx - ax) * (bx - ax)) + ((by - ay) * (by - ay))) * 2.54 / 96);
            break;
        case 2:
            cx = ball.getX();
            cy = ball.getY();

            length = Math.round(Math.sqrt((double) ((cx - bx) * (cx - bx)) + ((by - cy) * (by - cy))) * 2.54 / 96);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        area = length * width;
        canvas.drawText("length = " + length + "cm", (cx + bx) / 2, (by + cy) / 2, paint);
        canvas.drawText("width = " + width + "cm", (bx + ax) / 2, (by + ay) / 2, paint);
        canvas.drawText("area = " + area + "cm", (cx + ax) / 2, (cy + ay) / 2, paint);
    }
}
```

I can't find where is the error here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
public class RegInfo{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
}
```

In the onDraw() method class:

```
ArrayList<RegInfo> lists = new ArrayLists<RegInfo>();
```

Every Time you draw a rectangle,You can first draw the rectange which info saved in the lists and the draw the new rectange and save its info to the lists.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're a life saver! I'll try this one first. :)

Comment: Please edit your original answer to add information, rather than posting a new one.

Comment: get it!!Thank you so much!

Comment: @hongbochen It worked great! Sorry for the late reply. Thank you so much for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Because ervery time you draw a rectangle,The screen will be repainted.So you should save the rectangle ervery time you draw the rectangle.

Comment: How do I do that? Please I need help so bad!

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `canvas.drawRect(x, y, w, h, p)` you can also just store them in array of RectF directly instead of making a class separate for it. For example in **Kotlin**:

```
private var drawnRectangles: MutableList<RectF> = mutableListOf()
```

Then accessing the rectangles in the array. (In the onDraw method)

```
for (rect in drawnRectangles) {
    canvas.drawRect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, mPaint)
}
```

So every time you are done drawing you add the drawn rectangle to the array this way it stays stored while you draw a new rectangle.